# Logarithmic y-axis Tick Marks in R plot() or ggplot2()

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, data-visualization

I saw the ideal tick-mark structure for a `log="y"` plot in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0412004), Figure 3b 3c 3d.

It has short, log-spaced minor tick marks without labels, plus long, log-spaced major tick marks with labels.

Does anyone know how to achieve this in `R`?

Comment: Many correct answers. @Aaron's is plain R, @Richie's is ggplot, and @DWin's is a package just for this purpose.

Comment: To my eye, these look very heavy.  Which is one reason they're not easy to do in ggplot2.

Comment: @hadley Well, you are the expert. What would you do to achieve the same conceptual effect?

Comment: Well, pale grey would help, as would not doing quite so many of them.  I think pale grey lines in the plot background would also help.

Comment: I wrote a function for ggplot2 which uses minor ticks automatically, depending on the range of the data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54325289/3082472

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In base R just build the axes however you want.  Something like this could be a start.

```
set.seed(5)
d <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=rlnorm(100, meanlog=5, sdlog=3))
with(d, {
  plot(x, y, log="y", yaxt="n")
  y1 <- floor(log10(range(y)))
  pow <- seq(y1[1], y1[2]+1)
  ticksat <- as.vector(sapply(pow, function(p) (1:10)*10^p))
  axis(2, 10^pow)
  axis(2, ticksat, labels=NA, tcl=-0.25, lwd=0, lwd.ticks=1)
})
```

In `lattice`, the `latticeExtra` package has the capability:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
xyplot(y~x, data=d, scales=list(y=list(log=10)),
       yscale.components=yscale.components.log10ticks)
```

Comment: this is perfect! I just added `par(las=1)` and now it looks exactly like the article above. Wonderful, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

For `ggplot2`, it seems that the only option you have for specifying ticks is the `size` (i.e., width).

```
# A plot of any old data
dfr <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = rlnorm(100))
p <- ggplot(dfr, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = breaks, labels = breaks)


#Tick locations
get_breaks <- function(x)
{
  lo <- floor(log10(min(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
  hi <- ceiling(log10(max(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
  as.vector(10 ^ (lo:hi) %o% 1:9)
}

breaks <- get_breaks(dfr$y)
log10_breaks <- log10(breaks)

#Some bigger ticks
p + opts(axis.ticks = theme_segment(
    size = ifelse(log10_breaks == floor(log10_breaks), 2, 1)
  ))
```

Answer (score 3):

This has been done in package::sfsmisc. See the example in help(axTexpr)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `ggplot2` solution:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(20180407)

df = data.frame(x = seq(from = 1, by = 1, length.out = 20),
                y = 2^(seq(to = 1, by = -1, length.out = 20) + rnorm(20, 0, 0.7)))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_log10() +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "l")
```

[image: example_plot]

You can make it look even more than the paper you linked to with some theming:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_line(colour = "blue") +
  geom_point(colour = "blue") +
  scale_y_log10() +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "l") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_line())
```

[image: example_themed]