# R ggplot, two scales together

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, scale, axis

I want the y-axis to be scaled:

1. by log10, I used:

   **scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10",function(x) 10^x))**
2. more ticks:

   **scale_y_continuous(breaks=pretty_breaks(10))**

But from the error message, there can by only one scale.
Is there a way to have both of the two scales?

Comment: Sounds confusing. You probably want to consider faceting. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/how-to-use-ggplot2-make-plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if I understand your question right, you want to have a y axis on a log scale with more ticks than just 1, 10, 100, etc. Here's a reproducible example describing what you tried:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
dat <- data.frame(X=1:3, Y=c(2,50,10000))
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=X, y=Y)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_y_log10(breaks=trans_breaks("log10",function(x) 10^x)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=pretty_breaks(10))

## Error: Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will replace the existing scale.
```

OK, this error says we're only allowed one call to `scale_y_something`. Since you want log scale, let's keep `scale_y_log10`. Our approach from here depends on what you want to achieve - would it work to simply have more evenly spaced ticks along your axis, even if they aren't nice round numbers? If so, you can let `pretty()` add additional breaks by choosing a higher-than-normal value for `n` (which `?trans_breaks` promises will be passed to `pretty`):

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=X, y=Y)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_y_log10(breaks=trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x, n=20))
```

Flexible, maybe, but ugly. You can explore what trans_breaks is doing by applying the result to your data (`dat$Y` in this example). Note that the value of `n` is taken as a suggestion rather than a command:

```
trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x, n=2 )(dat$Y)
[1]     1   100 10000

trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x, n=10)(dat$Y)
[1]     1.000     3.162    10.000    31.623   100.000   316.228  1000.000  3162.278 10000.000
```

Or maybe you'd prefer ticks of the form 1, 3, 10, 30, 100, etc.? If so:

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=X, y=Y)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_y_log10(breaks=c(1,3,10,30,100,300,1000,3000,10000))
```

My guess is these direct specifications are your best bet. But if you also need flexibility for an arbitrary y range, take a hint from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14258838/3203184 and add a labels argument:

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=X, y=Y)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_y_log10(breaks=trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x, n=20), 
                labels=trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))
```