# Don't want to display all labels for minor ticks from ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I searched and found a similar post in Python not R.  I am using Richie Cotton's code in this post [Logarithmic y-axis Tick Marks in R plot() or ggplot2()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821763/logarithmic-y-axis-tick-marks-in-r-plot-or-ggplot2). I don't want to display all labels for minor ticks, I only want to display major ticks such as 1, 10, 100 etc.  Please see an exampled image below, that's why I don't want to display all minor tick's labels. I tried to remove "labels=breaks"[image] in the code, but nothing happened.

```
library(ggplot2)

dfr <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = rlnorm(100))

p <- ggplot(dfr, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = breaks, labels = breaks)

get_breaks <- function(x){
  lo <- floor(log10(min(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
  hi <- ceiling(log10(max(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
  as.vector(10 ^ (lo:hi) %o% 1:9)
}

breaks <- get_breaks(dfr$x)

log10_breaks <- log10(breaks)

p + labs(axis.ticks = element_line(
  size = ifelse(log10_breaks == floor(log10_breaks), 2, 1)
  ))
```

Comment: Don't you get what you want with just `ggplot(dfr, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + scale_x_log10()`? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @MrFlick OP wants the minor ticks w/o numbers

Comment: @MrFlick, I want to have all minor ticks on the x-axis, but I don't want to display their labels. Please look at the image above.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this.

```
ggplot(dfr, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = breaks, labels = c(breaks[1:3], rep("", 24)))
```

**yields:**

[image]

Comment: It really worked on a sample example, when I put in my app and ran.  I had the following error " Error : 'breaks' and 'labels' must have the same length".  Please explain when you hard-coded this "labels = c(breaks[1:3], rep("", 24))".  Thank you.

Comment: Take a look into `breaks`. In your example `breaks[1:3]` are the tick values that you want, the others you can fill with `""`. You also could say `rep("", length(breaks)-3)`. If there are e.g. thousands too it could be `breaks[1:4]`  Consider `length(breaks)`. Hope this would clarify a bit.